# Can IE/Google Chrome Frame access HTML5 whitelist resources when loaded through cache?

Tags: manifest, google-chrome-frame

Are there special IE security settings or headers I need to set to allow the request through from the Chrome BHO?  If not, then what's blocking my AJAX calls?

My HTML5 app uses AJAX to access a resource that is listed in the whitelist (NETWORK section) of the manifest.  With the IE cache cleared, the app loads and accesses a JSON resource with HTTP status 200.

If I close the IE window, and then in a new IE window navigate to that app, the app is loaded from the cache.  However, access to my JSON resource results in an HTTP status 0 with a message, "communcations failure".

While investigating this, I found that the page is not trusted by IE.
Without the Google BHO meta tag in the page's header, the page is trusted.  Add the meta tag back to the header, the page is not trusted.

This problem is specific to IE/Google Chrome Frame.  Chrome browser, for example, works when loaded from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Google (Chromium project) has fixed the problem.  Release pending.

See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76439